How to optimize a query?
I have a T-SQL query that run during 6 minutes.
There is several sub-query on the same table in it. I think it is the cause of the problem.
But I have no idea for optimizing it.
SELECT  dateheure, bac, presence, reponse
    ,(select top 1 dateheure from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure < t1.dateheure order by id desc) as dateheure_precedente
    ,(select top 1 presence from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure < t1.dateheure order by id desc) as presence_precedente 
    ,(select top 1 reponse from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure < t1.dateheure order by id desc) as reponse_precedente   
    ,(select top 1 dateheure from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure > t1.dateheure order by id asc) as dateheure_suivante
    ,(select top 1 presence from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure > t1.dateheure order by id asc) as presence_suivante
    ,(select top 1 reponse from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure > t1.dateheure order by id asc) as reponse_suivante
FROM [alpla_log].[dbo].[LogEvents] t1 
WHERE 
    t1.presence = 7845
    AND dateheure BETWEEN '11/07/2024 00:00:00' AND '11/07/2024 23:59:59.997' 
ORDER BY id DESC


The only table used is "LogEvents"
CREATE TABLE LogEvents (
    id int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    dateheure datetime NULL,
    type varchar(50) NULL,
    msg varchar(MAX) NULL,
    presence int NULL,
    destination int NULL,
    status_prt int NULL,
    reponse int NULL,
    bac int NULL
);

You can find the execution plan here.
I tried to add index on the table but it make no difference.
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ON dbo.Logevents (bac, dateheure) INCLUDE (reponse)
There are no other index.
The table is log of events in an automatic warehouse. It save the position of boxes on differents places. I want to find the previous and next position of every box compared with a specific place.
EDIT :
With use of LEAD and LAG function, the query execution time is now around 500ms.

For query performance questions, we need at a minimum: the tables and indexes involved and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. It's not really answerable otherwise.

Why would you not "select top 1, datheure, prescense, response, etc. from LogEvents WHERE" one time? Each of those selects is doing the same thing. And, doing the calculation, date from parts, pretty much guarantees index scans. You want to avoid that kind of thing entirely. However, at the root, you need to get the execution plan and figure out how SQL server is resolving the query for you. That will lead you to understanding what has to change.

A combination of: LEAD LAG window functions, fixing the WHERE to use a range, and removing the ORDER BY, and an index (bac, dateheure) INCLUDE (presence, reponse) would probably fix it for you https://dbfiddle.uk/LJcTmZ7k but again hard to say without more info.

Read about OUTER APPLY, no need to do this correlated subquery TOP 1 thingy multiple times

ALso    AND DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year,dateheure),DATEPART(month,dateheure),DATEPART(day,dateheure)) = '11/07/2024'
, why not just make it: year,dateheure between '20240711' and '20240711 23:59:59.997'

>= ... < logic would be better, @siggemannen : dateheure >= '20240711' AND dateheure  < '20240712' That's completely inclusive.

@ThomA yeah good call, i'm so used to date part coming as immutable string, but your variant is definitely better

You can see the difference with the suggestions I made https://dbfiddle.uk/Ex0uXTTI a single scan of the index, no key lookup, and no sorts. The index you tried did not have presence in the INCLUDE.

Your query can be significantly improved.

While you could replace the six subqueries with two APPLYs, a much better solution is to use LEAD and LAG window functions.

Note that LEAD and LAG will not give a result for the last/first row in the partition. You may need to put the whole thing in a derived table with a wider date range, then filter it back down afterwards.


The WHERE clause is not "sarge-able" (cannot use indexes). Instead use a date range, preferably a half-open interval >= AND <
Remove the ORDER BY if it's not absolutely necessary, as it's a different order from the WHERE and the PARTITION BY of the LEAD.

SELECT
  dateheure,
  bac,
  presence,
  reponse,
  LAG(t1.dateheure) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.bac ORDER BY t1.dateheure, t1.id) as dateheure_precedente,
  LAG(t1.presence ) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.bac ORDER BY t1.dateheure, t1.id) as presence_precedente,
  LAG(t1.reponse  ) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.bac ORDER BY t1.dateheure, t1.id) as reponse_precedente,
  LEAD(t1.dateheure) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.bac ORDER BY t1.dateheure, t1.id) as dateheure_suivante,
  LEAD(t1.presence ) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.bac ORDER BY t1.dateheure, t1.id) as presence_suivante,
  LEAD(t1.reponse  ) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.bac ORDER BY t1.dateheure, t1.id) as reponse_suivante
FROM LogEvents t1 
WHERE 
    t1.presence = 7845
    AND dateheure >= '20240711'
    AND dateheure < '20240712';

Finally add the correct index to support this query. The index you had was not taking presence into account.
CREATE INDEX IX ON LogEvents (presence, bac, dateheure, id) INCLUDE (reponse);

You can see from this fiddle that this now results in a single scan of the base table, no joins, no key lookups and no sorts.

Good answer. I was about to post an OUTER APPLY based solution, but this should have much better performance. The only disadvantage is that the first/last row for each bac, might not show previous/next values if they would fall outside the filtered date range. Also, if dateheure might have duplicate values, using ORDER BY t1.dateheure, T1.id might be needed.

Fair points, thanks

One very basic mistake is that you are querying same big table multiple times.
Instead you should put the main result in #temp table then query on Temp table.
This will give you performance gain. After this you may apply Window function or Outer apply in 2nd step query
There is 2 step involve but there is performance gain
SELECT  
    id, dateheure, bac, presence, reponse
    --,(select top 1 dateheure from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure < t1.dateheure order by id desc) as dateheure_precedente
    --,(select top 1 presence from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure < t1.dateheure order by id desc) as presence_precedente 
    --,(select top 1 reponse from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure < t1.dateheure order by id desc) as reponse_precedente   
   -- ,(select top 1 dateheure from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure > t1.dateheure order by id asc) as dateheure_suivante
   -- ,(select top 1 presence from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure > t1.dateheure order by id asc) as presence_suivante
   -- ,(select top 1 reponse from LogEvents where bac = t1.bac and dateheure > t1.dateheure order by id asc) as reponse_suivante
INTO
    #temp
FROM
    [alpla_log].[dbo].[LogEvents] t1 
WHERE 
    t1.presence = 7845
    AND dateheure BETWEEN '11/07/2024 00:00:00' AND '11/07/2024 23:59:59.997' 
--ORDER BY id DESC

Then 2ns step,
SELECT * 
--write other query here
FROM #temp
ORDER BY id DESC

